# using expr string : regex to cut strings

Tags: regex, sh

Theres a long string, containing space delimited words, one of them ends with $somevar.
Simple version is (x is $somevar):

```
expr "abc aac bbcx" : '.*\([^ ]\+x\).*'
```

The problem is, it only returns "cx". It should return "bbcx". Whats wrong here?

Comment: I am not following my friend. .*\([^ ]\+x\).* doesn't seem to match your input string.

Comment: @FailedDev on some systems which also use the "obsolete REs", or basic REs, (BSDs and Darwin/MacOS are two I know) as far as I remember the `+` metacharacter is not available. Try something like `{1,}` or `\{1,\}`, and be sure to check `re_format(7)` man page.

Comment: @Łukasz, this happens because the first atom encountered (`.*`) matches everything. Then, as it's not possible to continue with the regex, it backtracks up to a match of `[^ ]` to satisfy the expression, and continues the match from there. It's valid, but what you really want is a un-greedy atom in the beginning to match as few as possible before continuing. Not sure how to do it, though. This generally depends heavily in the OS and set of tools. Are you using GNU/Linux? (just guessing by the avatar :-)

Comment: thanks sidyll, I now know the reason it didn't work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.* is greedy - it matches as many characters as it can. Change it to .*? to make it match as few as it can:

```
.*?([^ ]+x).*?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following regex: `[^\s]+x\b`

Answer (score 0):

```
kent$  echo "abc aac bbcx"|grep -Po "[^\s]+(?=x)"                                                                                        
bbc
```

if you need the 'x' too: and you mentioned

> one of them **ends** with $somevar

```
kent$  echo "abc aac bbcx"|grep -Po "[^\s]+x(?=\s|$)"
bbcx

kent$  echo "abc aacx bbc"|grep -Po "[^\s]+x(?=\s|$)"
aacx
```